# Assistant Editor not displaying correct view controller?

Tags: xcode

Just a trivial kind of question. I've got a small project open which has two scenes, and two corresponding view controllers. They are matched up properly, with each scene having its own view controller which I set in 'custom class' under identity inspector.

When I have the second scene selected, and then click on assistant editor, the assistant editor brings up the view controller for the other scene. Is this a normal tick in Xcode? Can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode sometimes behaves like this. I haven't figured how the assistant editor decides what to show, though you can always change it by selecting something else from this list: (top left of the assistant editor, next to the `<` `>` buttons)

[image]

---

Credit to [vrwim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009013/vrwim):

When you select any of the automatic options and Xcode doesn't show the correct one, do a build and check the list again. This fixes it most of the time.

Comment: To build on this, when you select any of the automatic options and Xcode doesn't show the correct one, do a build and check the list again. This fixes it most of the time.

Comment: Great, thanks both. I think in hindsight this may have been happening because it was a new view controller and the project didn't recognise it in the same way? Great tip re re building.