# Assistant editor(Xcode 7.3) always showing interface file in storyboard , even when I choose manually

Tags: ios, swift, editor, xcode7.3, assistant

Even after deleting derived data many times, and trying other things, I am still facing this problem. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Try to more elaborate.

Answer (score 31):

You can try using the **shortcut key** instead, to open up the assistant editor.

Shortcut key: -

**`option + click on the file`** which you want to open up in the **`assistant editor`**

Comment: Good tip but doesn't help me, get error message "Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named ***". All the classes are set accordingly in XIB & I've confirmed the names are equal many times

Comment: That is totally a different scenario @AlexanderTelegin but, the error sometimes occurs due to the insufficient space between the codes. I'm not exactly sure, but when i face this problem, I do the same.

Answer (score 6):

Guys I just stop dealing with this problem by changing the settings in xcode 9.2. And now i use Navigation Pane.

Here is how it works :

Ok now if you go to xcode -> preferences -> navigation
and Choose the "Uses Focused Editor" as in the picture below.

[image]

**Now you can manually select inside the Navigation Pane.**
Just click whichever page you would like to change and select in the **Navigation Pane**.

Here is a few screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Pictures shows code files but it works with everything you can click in the Navigation Pane.

Answer (score 5):

Try to drag and drop file from the Project Navigator into the path of the Assistant Editor as temporary fix.
You also can click on this icon to bring recent files.

[image]

Try to clean your project, clean Build Folder, restart Xcode.
Make sure the view controller in your Storyboard has correct custom class name.

Comment: All the cleans don't help me just like they don't help OP. The hack you provide opens the file "manually" and outlets don't get created with an error:   "Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named ***"

Answer (score 4):

I think I know the problem you're having. I experience it too, but it's intermittent. Sometimes clicking `Manual` shows me the entire project folder and I can select the editable classes, but other times it only shows the interface versions of them, which aren't editable and cannot have IBOutlets dragged to them (you can tell b/c it'll say `internal class` and has less code). I have noticed that if I toggle back and forth between `Automatic` and `Manual`, I can usually get the editable class to appear. I also will toggle the assistant editor off, select a different View Controller or two on the storyboard, then go back to my original one, turn the Assistant Editor back on, and it starts working again.

There are other discussions of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38946752/1359088), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29062918/1359088), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230506/assistant-editor-not-displaying-correct-view-controller). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35207616/1359088) suggestion of turning off indexing sounds intriguing and worth a try if the problem keeps reappearing. UPDATE: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39288301/1359088) trick with hitting the `+` and opening a 2nd file, then closing the interface file, worked great when I tried it just now.

Here are pics of how the `Automatic` side shows the actual file when the `Manual` side only shows the interface, which says `internal` next to `class`:

[image]

[image]